# Gradle dependency library with an older version of my other dependency library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libraries

I'm trying to add an external library to my Android project in Android Studio.
Unfortunatelly one of my third-party libraries (lets call it `libraryA.jar`) contains modified version of another library (`libraryB1`). In my project I need to use this library in an unmodified and newer version (`libraryB2`). They are being represented in my gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/libraryA.jar')
    compile 'libraryB2'
}
```

Unfortunately every time I try to refer to the `libraryB2`, I get a reference to `libraryB1`.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a solution... I found a bit "dirty" way to make it work in my case. I downloaded sources of library B2 and then changed the name of the library's package. I added it as a module to my project and set the proper gradle dependency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transitive file dependencies in gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294976/transitive-file-dependencies-in-gradle)

Comment: I just ran into this problem myself. Hope this question had an answer.